# javascript d3 timeParse utcParse

Tags: javascript, d3.js, web-frontend

Would anyone have a tip on how to parse data that comes thru like this?

```
2020-07-02 15:27:05.000000,73.78999328613281
2020-07-02 15:42:10.000000,73.9699935913086
2020-07-02 15:57:16.000000,73.70999145507812
2020-07-02 16:12:21.000000,73.90999603271484
2020-07-02 16:27:26.000000,74.27999114990234
2020-07-02 16:42:32.000000,74.07999420166016
2020-07-02 16:57:37.000000,73.99999237060547
2020-07-02 17:12:42.000000,74.2699966430664
2020-07-02 17:27:47.000000,74.28999328613281
2020-07-02 17:42:52.000000,74.14999389648438
2020-07-02 17:57:56.000000,73.9699935913086
```

I am trying to experiment with `timeParse` and `utcParse` with d3 library.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Load d3.js -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

    <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

  </head>

    <script>
        time = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")("1/2/2014 8:22:05 AM");
        console.log(time);
    
    
        time2 = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%dT %H:%M:%S")("2020-07-02 17:57:56.000000");
        console.log(time2);

    </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

[I am trying to follow the d3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#utcParse), but when viewing the html file thru the dev console this will yeild null for the `utcParse attempt`. Would anyone have any tips?

```
Date Thu Jan 02 2014 08:22:05 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
test.html:17:11
null
```

Comment: From the d3 docs, `Parsing is strict: if the specified string does not exactly match the associated specifier, this method returns null.`  And your data doesn't contain a T between the date and time portions yet your specifier has a T.  Try removing the T.

Comment: removing the `T` still yields null. I may try finding a way to manipulate the data so it isnt the UTC format

Comment: Would you have any tips with Python and pandas to manipulate the `Date` in a format? What date & time format contains the `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [the d3 format docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format) as a reference, you need to build a specifier that exactly matches your data (or you will get "null" 100% of the time).

You'll notice in the docs that `%S` refers to a 2-digit decimal number of seconds - Uh oh, we have seconds and then six decimals (microseconds) in the data.
So, instead of just `%S`, we want `%S` followed by the decimal point followed by the `%f` directive which is 6 digits of microseconds.

The "T" in between the date and time portions is just part of the date format, UTC and ISO-8601 (and others probably) use a T in that position.  The output of the snippet shows the date in UTC format with the T.

```js
time2 = d3.utcParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")("2020-07-02 17:57:56.000000");
console.log(time2);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```